# Google Map FitBounds not centering over markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For some reason I am really struggleing with fitBounds. Here is my function I am using to render the map, plot some markers and (hopefully) center the map around the markers. Everything is working great. Markers are in correct spot - only thing left is to center the map. Right now, it's putting me out in the middle of the ocean.

```
// locations is a json object coming from an ajax response
// Sample response: ["MyTown, State (12345)"]
renderMap: function(locations) {
        var that = this;
        var map;
        var bounds;
        var idle;
        var markerArray = [];
        var marker = {};
        var markerLatLng = {};
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), mapOptions);
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        $.each(locations, function(key, val) {
            that.geoCodeAddress(val, function(geoCodeAddressResponse) {
                switch (geoCodeAddressResponse.status)
                {
                    case 'success': // Do work!
                        markerLatLng = {
                            lat: geoCodeAddressResponse.lat,
                            lng: geoCodeAddressResponse.lng
                        };

                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            'map': map,
                            'clickable': true,
                            'position': markerLatLng,
                            'animation': google.maps.Animation.DROP
                        });

                        bounds.extend(marker.position); 
                        break;
                    case 'fail':  // Could not get latlng for location.
                        break;
                    default: // Epic fail.
                        break;
                }
            });
        });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

I have been using [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5R63/) as reference. I am getting the same output for this line: `marker.position`:

```
{k: 12.1234567, A: -34.12345678912345, toString: function, j: function, equals: function…}
```

(the lat/lng are just example numbers)

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Geocoding is asynchronous, you are calling map.fitBounds before any of the results are back from the server.

Comment: I think it's gotta be a timing problem as well. Are you suggesting that the map.fitBounds call is executing before the each loop is complete?

Comment: It is. The geocoder is asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a step back and give another shot.